# Creating a complex 2D-array from two 2D-real-arrays ? - Python 3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, complex-numbers

Consider the following two real 2D-array

```
real = [x_00,x_01,....,x_0m]
       [x_10,x_11,....,x_1m]
       ......
       [x_n0,x_n1,....,x_nm]

imag = [y_00,y_01,....,y_0m]
       [y_10,y_11,....,y_1m]
       ......
       [y_n0,y_n1,....,y_nm]
```

Im looking for a fast method (in my case  n = 10**7) to convert the imag array to a complex one and add it to the reall array

z = x + i*imag

In the end i want a complex array with the following output (basic matrix addition):

```
z = [x_00 + i * y_00, x_01 + i * y_01, ... , x_0m + i*y_0m]
     ....
    [x_n0 + i * y_n0, x_n1 + i * y_n1, ... , x_nm + i*y_nm]
```

Example Code:

```
real = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
imag = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

Looking for output:

```
z = np.array([[1+1j, 2+2j],[3+3j, 4+4j]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply

```
z=real+1j*imag
```

(using your `np.array`s)